# passing objective c variable to javascript in ios

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

How to pass a ObjectiveC string Variable to a javascript function? I have just started with javascript.. so plz 4give my ignorance...

Comment: Some more information would be useful. Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: Suppose the JS function is myFunc(var arg1)
I Have NSString * str = some value.
Now, [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:.......]
Here how to pass the str as a argument to the Js function myFunc()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSString * param  = @"foo";   
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc('%@')",param];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Comment: What if my param is object or array? Not a "foo" string?

Comment: Is there any alternate way. I am trying to pass my complete web-service response so it is crashing.

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C

```
NSString *str  = @"hi ya";   
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc('%@')",str]];
```

Now call this function in the js file:

```
function myFunc(str)
{
   alert(str);
}
```

These steps should work.