# Passing Javascript Variable to Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, variables

I've seen how to pass an Objective-C variable to JavaScript right here, [passing objective c variable to javascript in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641968/passing-objective-c-variable-to-javascript), but how do I pass a variable from JavaScript to Objective-C when I'm using something like this:

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"u\");"
"passThisVarToObjC = elems.length;"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, this is what we call **stringly typed**.

Because the return type of `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` is `NSString *`, you will either need to stick to using a string or coercing the value into some other (*read:more usable*) type.

But anyway, `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` will return the value of a JavaScript variable to you without a problem.

The way this is accomplished is through the use of an anonymous function (which in this case is self-executing):

```
NSString *numOfElements = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function() {var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"u\"); return elems.length;})();"];

//do normal stuff with numOfElements like cast to an int or something cool like that.
```

Comment: Could you please help me on this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793698/how-to-make-image-maps-clickable-using-uiwebview-in-iphone

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a return statement in your javascript. There may be better ways to do it but the following javascript works for me:

```
    NSString* findLink = @"function f() {var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
if(x.length > 0) { return x[0].getAttribute('href');}; return null;} f(); ";
```

Try using this code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function f() {var elems =
document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"u\"); return elems.length;}f();"];
```