# Pass Value from iOS to uiWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I can successfully obtain a variable from javascript and display it as an alert message in an iOS app as follows:

```
    let loggedIn = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "loggedIn");

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:
        loggedIn, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above works perfectly.  Is there a similar option to pass a variable from iOS to a javascript variable and run a function that does a pop alert with that variable?

Any help, as always, is appreciated.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: passing "loggedIn=true" will set loggedIn as true. similar way you can even call functions with parameters if you want. for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641968/passing-objective-c-variable-to-javascript-in-ios

Comment: Many thanks.  Did not realise it was that simple.  Feel free to put it as the answer.  If you could pop an example of swift 3 and the function with parameter that would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift code to call javascript method

```
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "myFunction('param')")
```

javascript method

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
```

Reference [passing objective c variable to javascript in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641968/passing-objective-c-variable-to-javascript-in-ios)

Hope this helps.